# Decoding base64 text file to audio file returns invalid argument of input file

Tags: base64

I am following [these instructions](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/create-audio-text-command-line#mac-osx); however, when I run the command:

```
base64 --decode synthesize-output-base64.txt > synthesize-output-audio.mp3
```

on macOS, I get the following error:

```
base64: invalid argument synthesize-output-base64.txt
```

I've tried searching for this issue but am unable to find a similar one.  Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On macOS the syntax is a little different.

base64 -D -i synthesize-output-base64.txt > synthesize-output-audio.mp3